Cannot receive UDP packets in Flutter
I have a camera that is supposed to be transferring a live video stream to my flutter app by way of UDP packets (confirmed in Wireshark), but for some reason I'm not receiving them.
The port number for the source seems to randomly change each time I begin a new stream, so I set the source port number to 0, but I'm somehow only getting a WRITE event back.
Am I missing something here?
` Future<void> _getUdpData() async {
    try {
      final datagramSocket = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0);
      datagramSocket.broadcastEnabled = true;
      datagramSocket.readEventsEnabled = true;
      print('Datagram socket ready to receive');
      print('${datagramSocket.address.address}:${datagramSocket.port}');
      datagramSocket.listen((RawSocketEvent event) {
        print('Socket event: $event');
        if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
          _handleReadEvent(datagramSocket);
        }
      });
    } catch (event) {
      print('Error retrieving data: $event');
    }
  }

  void _handleReadEvent(RawDatagramSocket datagramSocket) {
    Datagram? dg = datagramSocket.receive();
    if (dg != null) {
      String message = String.fromCharCodes(dg.data).trim();
      print('Datagram from ${dg.address.address}:${dg.port}: $message');
    } else {
      print('No datagram received.');
    }
  }`

All the documentation I've found has had some version of the setup I already have, so this is confusing the heck out of me.
An example of the data passage on Wireshark

You would expect the UDP source port to be random, but what is the destination port?  Either it should be fixed or there is some method by which the camera can tell you or you can tell the camera which destination port to send to. You can't just listen on udp port 0.

@Paulw11 I tried to bind it to port 4444 and still got the same result.

Ok, but how do you know that the camera is sending on port 4444? Is that the destination that wire shark shows? Is that what you configured in the camera itself? What ip address is the camera sending to? Is that the ip address of your receiving device? Are you running in a real device or a simulated device?

@Paulw11 That's the issue. The source and destination port seems to change with each new use, and I have no access to the cameras underlying OS, so I can't force it to use certain ports.
The camera provides it's own wifi connections, so the source is 192.168.100.1 and the destination is 192.168.100.2
I've tried running in a sim and a real device. Same issue

Then you need more information on how the camera advertises the port it is going to use.

@Paulw11 Agreed. It's strange that on wireshark it's seems to be showing port 0 (and that doesn't work) but for some reason, at other times there is an actual port being used and I can bind to that port and it works perfect.

If it shows port 0 then it might be broadcasting.  What is the destination address for that packet? 255.255.255.255 ?

@Paulw11 The destination address is 192.168.100.2. I added a snippet from Wireshark in my question showing what I'm seeing
